# change a part of a word

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to figure out how to do this:

```
>>>sentence = "There's something right there."
>>>change_s(sentence)
['there', 'his', 'something', 'right', 'there.']
>>>sentence = "it's Patrick's car."
>>>change_s(sentence)
['it', 'his', 'Patrick', 'his', 'car.']
```

So basically I want to change "'s" to "his" (even if it's grammatically not correct) and put the words in a list.

Comment: You are aware that "it his" != "it's", right?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [6]: sentence = "There's something right there."

In [7]: sentence.replace("'s", " his").split()
Out[7]: ['There', 'his', 'something', 'right', 'there.']
```

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Been a long day, thanks for the suggestion.